# Calling for where tinyint is 0 (used as boolean) in query

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently using tinyint to store boolean values in mysql, and am trying to query a database but it is failing. The error I am getting is `Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given` which if im not mistaken just means the query didn't work. Before I post the query let me say I am using practically deprecated php for the query, however it's not going live and I just need it to work real quick. I know this stuff is all being updated so feel free to share any relevant materials (I do need to get caught up as it is) however the solution I am looking for is for my old school query. The query is:

`$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contact ORDER BY id ASC WHERE read='0'");`

where read is the tinyint in question.

I have tried `WHERE read=0`
and `WHERE read=false`

None of these are working, I do appreciate any help in advance!

Comment: You now proudly receive the reminder to stop using mysql_ functions and switch to PDO or mysqli. mysql_ is soon to be totally deprecated.

Comment: Please give me material on PDO, I know it is nearly deprecated thanks.

Comment: i updated my response with links to both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to structure the query correctly:

```
"SELECT * FROM contact WHERE read=0 ORDER BY id ASC"
```

WHERE comes before ORDER BY.

Additionally, "mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource" is happening because you're calling a method on a failed query - not a resource. You could get a proper error on your query itself with something like `mysql_query("SELECT... your query") or die(mysql_error())` But officially we all suggest moving to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)
And using their respective error reporting utilities.

Comment: Oh that certainly helps lol, thanks I feel pretty stupid spending an hour researching why `read=0` wasnt working, thanks

Comment: Yeah, I'm really green with PDO and mysqli, but I know for the live stuff I'm going to have to learn all that real soon, for this project its just a temporary locally hosted site for use on an intranet so it doesn't really matter but I do want to get up to speed on all the good stuff :P thanks

Comment: The jump is pretty light, fortunately. It took all of maybe a day to get used to switching. So long as you're not afraid to read the docs you should be ok. I know it's a lot, but it's not like mysql syntax has changed. Only how you interact with it.

Comment: Yeah, I hope you are right I'll be taking that dive this weekend, pray for me :P